# ConvertTo-Json on array read from file yields unexpected results

Tags: json, powershell

Write an array to a file:

```
PS C:\Users\dharmatech\Downloads> 10, 20, 30 | Out-File 'test.txt'
```

Read the array back in and call `ConvertTo-Json` on it:

```
PS C:\Users\dharmatech\Downloads> ConvertTo-Json (Get-Content .\test.txt)
```

The result is not the JSON version of the array... See the result below.

If you call `Get-Member` on one of the strings in the array read from the file, you'll see that the string object has been annotated with a few `NoteProperty`s. I'm guessing that explains the `ConvertTo-Json` output.

What's a good way to get the JSON version of the array in the file, using `ConvertTo-JSON`?

```
[
    {
        "value":  "10",
        "PSPath":  "C:\\Users\\dharmatech\\Downloads\\test.txt",
        "PSParentPath":  "C:\\Users\\dharmatech\\Downloads",
        "PSChildName":  "test.txt",
        "PSDrive":  {
                        "CurrentLocation":  "Users\\dharmatech\\Downloads",
                        "Name":  "C",
                        "Provider":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem",
                        "Root":  "C:\\",
                        "Description":  "",
                        "Credential":  "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential",
                        "DisplayRoot":  null
                    },
        "PSProvider":  {
                           "ImplementingType":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider",
                           "HelpFile":  "System.Management.Automation.dll-Help.xml",
                           "Name":  "FileSystem",
                           "PSSnapIn":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core",
                           "ModuleName":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core",
                           "Module":  null,
                           "Description":  "",
                           "Capabilities":  52,
                           "Home":  "C:\\Users\\dharmatech",
                           "Drives":  "C D"
                       },
        "ReadCount":  1
    },
    {
        "value":  "20",
        "PSPath":  "C:\\Users\\dharmatech\\Downloads\\test.txt",
        "PSParentPath":  "C:\\Users\\dharmatech\\Downloads",
        "PSChildName":  "test.txt",
        "PSDrive":  {
                        "CurrentLocation":  "Users\\dharmatech\\Downloads",
                        "Name":  "C",
                        "Provider":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem",
                        "Root":  "C:\\",
                        "Description":  "",
                        "Credential":  "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential",
                        "DisplayRoot":  null
                    },
        "PSProvider":  {
                           "ImplementingType":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider",
                           "HelpFile":  "System.Management.Automation.dll-Help.xml",
                           "Name":  "FileSystem",
                           "PSSnapIn":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core",
                           "ModuleName":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core",
                           "Module":  null,
                           "Description":  "",
                           "Capabilities":  52,
                           "Home":  "C:\\Users\\dharmatech",
                           "Drives":  "C D"
                       },
        "ReadCount":  2
    },
    {
        "value":  "30",
        "PSPath":  "C:\\Users\\dharmatech\\Downloads\\test.txt",
        "PSParentPath":  "C:\\Users\\dharmatech\\Downloads",
        "PSChildName":  "test.txt",
        "PSDrive":  {
                        "CurrentLocation":  "Users\\dharmatech\\Downloads",
                        "Name":  "C",
                        "Provider":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem",
                        "Root":  "C:\\",
                        "Description":  "",
                        "Credential":  "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential",
                        "DisplayRoot":  null
                    },
        "PSProvider":  {
                           "ImplementingType":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider",
                           "HelpFile":  "System.Management.Automation.dll-Help.xml",
                           "Name":  "FileSystem",
                           "PSSnapIn":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core",
                           "ModuleName":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core",
                           "Module":  null,
                           "Description":  "",
                           "Capabilities":  52,
                           "Home":  "C:\\Users\\dharmatech",
                           "Drives":  "C D"
                       },
        "ReadCount":  3
    }
]
PS C:\Users\dharmatech\Downloads>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
10, 20, 30 | Out-File 'testfile1.txt'

convertto-json ([string[]](gc testfile1.txt))

[
    "10",
    "20",
    "30"
]
```

Or, if you want them as [int]

```
10, 20, 30 | Out-File 'testfile1.txt'

convertto-json ([int[]](gc testfile1.txt))

[
    10,
    20,
    30
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Get-Content has a bad habit of extending the strings it outputs with a whole lot of extra information.  This can cause memory bloat when dealing with large files. I wish Get-Content had a switch to enable these extra properties when needed which would be rare.  However, as this might break existing programs it is more feasible to ask for a parameter that strips off the extra properties. Perhaps something like `ValueOnly`?

To get around these problems you can cast as mjolinor shows above but for the best performance, drop down to .NET:

```
ConvertTo-Json ([IO.File]::ReadAllLines("$pwd\test.txt"))

[
    "10",
    "20",
    "30"
]
```

While this is unnecessary for anything but really large files, it is a good trick to have in your toolbox.